# Android GridView doesn't show any data in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment, android-gridview, android-adapterview

I create a DialogFragment which contains various filters to customize searches on app, but the gridView with the various category doesn't work at all. I tried a lot of different code and search everything on internet, but none of them solve my problem. Hope someone can help me.

**This is the Grid Adapter**

```
public class GridFilterAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    String[] category;

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public GridFilterAdapter(Context context, String[] category){
        this.context = context;
        this.category = category;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.category.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.column_filter, parent);
            Log.w("IO", "controllo l'inflate nell'if");
            /*view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.column_filter, parent);
            Log.w("IO", "controllo convertView nell'if");*/
        } else{
            view = convertView;
        }

        TextView text = view.findViewById(R.id.crossfit_filter);
        text.setText(category[position]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**This is my FragmentDialog**

```
public class FilterFragment extends DialogFragment {

    FragmentFilterBinding binding;

    public static String TAG = "Filtri ricerca";
    public FilterFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_filter,null);
        binding = FragmentFilterBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        view.setMinimumWidth((6 * width)/7);
        builder.setView(view);
        String[] item = {
                "Crossfit",
                "Boxe",
                "Running",
                "Body Building"
        };

        binding.gridtab.setAdapter(new GridFilterAdapter(getContext(), item));
        binding.gridtab.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Ho percepito il click su " + item[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_filter, container, false);

        return v;
    }

}
```

**And these are the xml file of the DialogFragment, fragment_filter.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="450dp"
    android:minWidth="1000dp"
    tools:context=".FilterFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/leftMargin_title">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/filter_title">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:text="FILTRI PER LA RICERCA"
            android:fontFamily="@font/encode_sans_medium"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/topMargin_title"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/topMargin_title"
            android:textColor="#3b3b3b"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/filter_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/filter_btn_gradient"
        android:layout_below="@id/filter_title"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cityFilter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/filter_divider"

        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/leftMargin_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/leftMargin_title"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/leftMargin_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/leftMargin_title"

        android:fontFamily="@font/encode_sans_semibold"
        android:text="Filtra per città"
        android:textColor="#212121"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_city"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/input_white_bck"
        android:layout_below="@id/cityFilter"

        android:hint="Città"
        android:textColorHint="#803b3b3b"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/encode_sans_medium"

        android:paddingStart="@dimen/topMargin_title"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/topMargin_title"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"

        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/topMargin_title"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/topMargin_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/leftMargin_title"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_evaluation_filter"
            android:layout_below="@id/search_city"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Filtra per recensione"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/encode_sans_semibold"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/leftMargin_title"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/leftMargin_title"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/leftMargin_title"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/leftMargin_title"
            />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_evaluation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_evaluation_filter"
        android:entries="@array/evaluation"

        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/topMargin_title"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/topMargin_title"

        android:padding="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_white_bck"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_category"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner_evaluation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Categoria di sport"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/encode_sans_semibold"
        android:textColor="#212121"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/leftMargin_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/leftMargin_title"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/leftMargin_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/leftMargin_title"
        />
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridtab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_category"

        android:numColumns="5"
        >

    </GridView>





</RelativeLayout>
```

**and xml for the Grid's items, column_filter.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crossfit_filter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/category_selector"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/topMargin_title"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/topMargin_title"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:fontFamily="@font/encode_sans_medium"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/topMargin_title"
        android:text="Rose"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```